# What is the difference between the situation calculus and the propositional logic of context?

Tags: propositional-logic

I have been reading a lot of papers by John McCarthy lately. As early as 1963, he developed [the situation calculus](http://scholar.google.fi/scholar_url?url=http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc%3FAD%3DAD0785031&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm1BWLUnxIrK7t0TDYa4d1TXqhLbQg&oi=scholarr&ei=oomuVNfDIIjyOIDYgegE&ved=0CB0QgAMoADAA), but then starting in 1987, he developed what came to be known as the propositional logic of context (PLC) ([McCarthy, 1987](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=33448); [McCarthy, 1993](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1624103)). Surprisingly, he doesn't really describe the relationship between situation and context or how one formalism fits into the other (or perhaps they don't, but he doesn't say that either).

I have come across [one paper](http://scholar.google.fi/scholar_url?url=http://cogprints.org/460/2/cipaper.ps&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0-Rpz_ajP0exEXBWLuLDDbkTLkqg&oi=scholarr&ei=wYquVIm_JIfUOPn0gLgN&ved=0CB8QgAMoADAA) that sheds some light on the relationship between situation and context, but it mainly discusses situation in the context of [situation theory](http://web.stanford.edu/~kdevlin/Papers/HHL_SituationTheory.pdf), which appears to be distinct from the situation calculus. Does anyone know of a good reference that discusses jointly the situation calculus and PLC? Or can you provide an explanation of their relationship here on SE?